# Non-time-based RollCycles?

Tags: chronicle, chronicle-queue

Chronicle Queue has the notion of RollCycles which determine when an appender will switch to a new file. Would it be possible to have RollCycles based on other criteria, for instance of current file size? It would switch to a new file if the current one will exceed a certain file size or number of records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a means of doing this as currently, the internal representation is time-based.

Instead, I suggest rolling often enough that the files are not too large. You can use roll cycles of 1, 5, 10, 15, 20, 30, 60, 120, 240, and 360 minutes, instead of daily.